# How to change the number of posts shown in a blogspot slidebartab widget which is based on post labels?

Tags: html, widget, numbers, posts, blogspot

I have a premium template of [this](http://gonzo-soratemplate.blogspot.com/). In this shown template its news widget has three tabs as Business, Fashion and Technology which are based on post labels same as the tab titles. Its one tab has only 5 posts as 2 big post in left and 3 small posts in right. But in the premium I got it shows 6 six posts when there are more than five posts with a same tab label. It is as 2 big posts just like in the demo template in the left side and 4 small posts in right side instead of 3 small posts. So it leaves an empty white space in my website below in the left side of the widget under the two big posts.

When I asked about this from the seller, he tells me to label only five posts by same tab title which is in my opinion very unpractical.  Because in that way I can't post a new post with a label without removing a label of old posts.

This premium have some other problems other than this like vanishing the top news widget entirely if a single post is made without a label, but this one is the major problem that makes the site unusable.

Can someone please help me to get this fixed to show only five posts in this news widget as shown in the demo, so there wouldn't be an unnecessary empty white space in the below of widget like now in my website.

I don't know which code of the template affects to change the number of posts shown in this widget, but here's the html part of the template relevant to this widget. If any other codes need I can upload them here or email.

```
<div id='mywrapper'>

    <!-- post wrapper start -->
    <div id='post-wrapper'>
        <div class='post-container'>
            <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>

<div id='sidebartab'>
    <div id='tab'>
        <!--Sidebar Tabs Widgets Started-->
        <div class='tab-widget-menu clear'>
            <ul>
                <li class='tab1'>
                    Business
                </li>
                <li class='tab2'>
                    Fashion
                </li>
                <li class='tab3'>
                    Technology
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class='clear'/>
        </div>

        <div class='widget1' id='tab1'>
            <b:section class='stylebox1 section' id='stylebox-1' showaddelement='yes'>
                <b:widget id='HTML73' locked='true' title='Business' type='HTML'>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                        <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
                        <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                            <div class='recent-post-title'>
                                <h2><data:title/></h2>
                            </div>
                        </b:if>

                        <div class='widget-content'>
                            <div class='news_pictures'>
                                <ul class='news_pictures_list'>
                                    <script>
                                        document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=mythumb1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
                                    </script>
                               </ul>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                      <b:include name='quickedit'/>
                  </b:includable>
              </b:widget>
          </b:section>
      </div>
      <div class='widget1' id='tab2'>
          <b:section class='stylebox1 section' id='stylebox-5' showaddelement='yes'>
              <b:widget id='HTML36' locked='true' title='Fashion' type='HTML'>
                  <b:includable id='main'>
                      <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
                      <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                          <div class='recent-post-title'>
                              <h2><data:title/></h2>
                          </div>
                      </b:if>

                      <div class='widget-content'>
                        <div class='news_pictures'>
                          <ul class='news_pictures_list'>
                            <script>
                              document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=mythumb1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
                            </script>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <b:include name='quickedit'/>
                    </b:includable>
                   </b:widget>
                 </b:section>
                </div>
                <div class='widget1' id='tab3'>
          <b:section class='stylebox1 section' id='stylebox-6' showaddelement='yes'>
            <b:widget id='HTML71' locked='true' title='Technology' type='HTML'>
              <b:includable id='main'>
                      <!-- only display title if it's non-empty -->
                      <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
                        <div class='recent-post-title'>
                          <h2><data:title/></h2>
                        </div>
                      </b:if>

                      <div class='widget-content'>
                        <div class='news_pictures'>
                          <ul class='news_pictures_list'>
                            <script>
                              document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=mythumb1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);
                            </script>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <b:include name='quickedit'/>
                    </b:includable>
            </b:widget>
          </b:section>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div style='clear: both;'/>
              <script type='text/javascript'>
                //<![CDATA[
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#tab .widget1').hide();
                  $('#tab .widget1:first').show();
                  $('.tab-widget-menu ul li:first').addClass('selected');
                  $('.tab-widget-menu ul li').click(function(){ 
                    $('.tab-widget-menu ul li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                    $('#tab .widget1').hide();
                    $('#tab .widget1').eq($('.tab-widget-menu ul li').index(this)).slideDown()(500);
                  });
                });
                //]]>
              </script>
              <!--Sidebar Tabs Widgets End-->
            </div>
                <div class='clear'/>
              </b:if>
              <div class='clear'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for `var numposts2 = 5, var numposts3 = 5`. Change the number you want to show.